# ImportError: No module named redis_cache

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, redis

I am using Django=1.5.4 and I have installed redis properly in ubuntu. I installed django-redis. But I get this error. I put 'redis_cache' in my django settings. But I got this error

```
ImportError: No module named redis_cache
```

What to do?

Comment: whats's the output of `python2 -c "import redis_cache"`

Answer (score 11):

You are supposed to add `django_redis` instead of `redis_cache`.

The [documentation](http://niwinz.github.io/django-redis/latest/#_installation) says:

> if you are coming from `django-redis < 3.8.x`, you are probably using
>   `redis_cache`. Since django-redis 3.8.x, `redis_cache` module is
>   deprecated in favor to `django_redis`. The `redis_cache` module will be
>   removed in 3.9.x versions.

Answer (score 8):

**Redis cache backend for Django**

Run `python setup.py install` to install, or place `django_redis` on your Python path.

You can also install it with: `pip install django-redis`

Comment: Thanks! It works for me on python 3.6 and django 1.11

Answer (score 1):

Use following command as available at [this](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/redis-simple-cache/):

```
pip install redis-simple-cache
```

Answer (score 0):

you are missing django_redis module run below command to add the module:

```
pip install django-redis
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using docker compose + poetry to manage dependencies, and the solution for me to get rid of this Redis error was:

- On Docker, delete all images and containers associated with the project
- On VSCode, run the command Python: Clear cache and reload windows
- Run docker compose up again

It seems like it was a cache issue, at least in my case.

Maybe there's a more surgical way of doing this, but these steps certainly are helpful when you've already double checked all dependencies and project settings.